# Java networking multiple simultaneous network requests

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I am developing an application for my ebay store to handle messages, shipments, product stock etc. I have a server running all the time (getting data via the ebay-api and storing it to a sqlite databse) and a client connecting to it.
At the moment my server is waiting for a connection from a client and once it is connecting a new Runnable is created. (Like it is explained in every Java networking tutorial)
The client requests data, like orders, messages etc. by sending serialized objects containing information about the required data and then the server sends back the requested objects.

My problem is that client always needs to wait for the answer before sending an other request, which can be really annoying if it takes the server a while to answer (for example because it needs to wait from an answer from the Ebay API).

Here is an example:

Client:

```
public boolean sendNewMessage(OutgoingMessage outgoingMessage) {
    SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest(outgoingMessage);
    try {
        out.writeObject(request);
        out.reset();
    
        Object obj = in.readObject();
        String status = (String) obj;
    
        if (status.equals("OK")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message send error: " + status);
            return false;
        }
    
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Server code in the WorkerRunnable:

```
while (isRunning()) {
    if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = in.readObject();
        } catch....
        .....   
        } else if (obj instanceof SendMessageRequest) {
            SendMessageRequest request = (SendMessageRequest) obj;        
                  
            OutgoingMessage outgoingMessage = request.getOutgoingMessage();
            String apiAnswer = ebayApi.sendNewMessage(outgoingMessage); //This might take a few seconds
               
            try {
                out.writeObject(apiAnswer);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

In that case I want to be able to send an other request to the server before getting the answer if the message got sent. (For example to click on the next message and get details about it from the database.)

How would I do something like that?

I guess I would need to start a separate thread on the client to receive the answer from the server but how would I separate the answer to that request from the other requests that I want to send during the waiting time?

And of course I would also need to do the API call from the server in a new thread, so the "WorkerRunnable" is able to reveive the next request.

Comment: Also there would be the problem that by creating new threads it could happen that two different threads would access the sqlite database simultaneously. How can I make shure nothing goes wrong there?

Comment: Have the client open another connection. The response arrives over the same connection the request was sent on.

Comment: Have you considered using non-blocking `SocketChannel`s?

Comment: NB The `isConnected()` test is pointless. It will never become false.

Comment: @nylanderdev That's essentially impossible with `ObjectInput/OutputStreams`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Undoubtedly

Comment: Okay. I went for the idea of @Marquis of Lorne. It seems like a hack but it works fine for my case.